# Why does <esc> on empty, indented line, jump to beginning?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, cut-copy-paste, indentation, neovide

I'm trying to do something very simple, enter normal mode and **ALWAYS** be able to somehow put the normal mode cursor where it was in insert mode, whether through a mark, or otherwise.

I'm doing this because my neovim GUI doesn't handle copy/paste and I need to map it myself. This is proving extremely painful and challenging to get it working properly, like how MacVim does it is perfect.

```
def hello
  puts "hi"
  |
end
```

If I hit `<esc>`

It enters normal mode but at the beginning of the line. this makes it hard to paste `"+P` exactly where the cursor was.

```
-- indentation
vim.opt.autoindent  = true -- continue indentation to new line
vim.opt.smartindent = true -- add extra indent when it makes sense
vim.opt.smarttab    = true -- <tab> at the start of a line behaves as expected
vim.opt.expandtab   = true -- <tab> inserts spaces
vim.opt.shiftwidth  = 2    -- >>, << shift line by 4 spaces
vim.opt.tabstop     = 2    -- <tab> appears as 4 spaces
vim.opt.softtabstop = 2    -- <tab> behaves as 4 spaces when editing

-- cursor
vim.opt.virtualedit = 'all'
```

Comment: `:help autoindent`